# how do I allow a single IP address to connect to a certain port?

Tags: windows, server, port, firewall

I wanna host a Minecraft server on my pc for my friends, and for it to be secure I want to be able to choose what IP addresses can connect to the port that will be needed to join. I have tried everything but there always seem to be something missing or going wrong. It's probably because it is a javascript file and not a executable? Anyway, any help is greatly appreciated!

I have tried going in the advanced firewall settings to allow a certain IP, but the option wasn't showing up when trying to make a rule for the port.